# Swift Any method argument Protocol Conformance Lost

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

```
protocol A { }
class B: A { }

func f(x: Any) {
    print(x is A)
}
let x: B? = B()
f(x: x) // false
```

I would expect this to be `true` instead. Is it a bug in Swift?

Following examples work fine and return `true`:

```
// 1
func f(x: Any) {
    print(x is A)
}
let x: B = B() // not optional
f(x: x) // true

// 2
func f(x: Any) {
    print(x is B) // check for B
}
let x: B? = B()
f(x: x) // true
```

Comment: Yup, [this is a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6279).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if your instance conforms to protocol A you can either use :

```
func<T>(x: T) {
   print(x is A)
}
```

Or use both functions in conjunction :

```
func(x: Any) {
   print(x is A)
}

func(x: Optional<Any>) {
   print(x is A)
}
```